# Parse class name

Tags: stylus

I wonder if there is any way to parse class name and interpolate part of it to mixin.

Example:
HTML

```
<div class="offset-37"></div>
<div class="offset-69"></div>
```

And Stylus (something like this):

```
offset-{@offset} {
 left: @offset + '%';
}
```

And in the end I will have a first div with left offset of 37% and second with offset of 69%.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Stylus doesn't know anything about html structure. So, it is impossible.